# The server Emacs can't recognize the ALT key when accessed by a Mac

Tags: linux, osx, emacs

I use Mac's ssh to get access to a server. I find the emacs on the server can not recognize the ALT key.  My server is RHEL with emacs23.

Comment: I don't think it's enough information, but I would check if the alt key you're pressing is interpreted as proper signal on your redhat. Might be that mac's interpreting it differently.

Comment: I agree. what other information do you need.

Comment: If you could check what signal is your alt sending to your system, then see  if it's the same on redhat, and what is this signal - that could be some starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the Terminal app, choose Terminal > Preferences...

This will bring up an options menu. Under Settings there's a tab for the keyboard.

The checkbox "Use option as a meta key" makes the Alt/Option key work like you expected (I tried it in Emacs and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. Just to update to Samuel's answer, the current working method is Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard > Tick checkbox with option 'Use option as Meta Key'.